# Xamarin iOS app localisation is not working

Tags: xamarin.ios, localization

I have an app which is in Xamarin iOS. I want to localise that app. I have tried below things for localising a storyboard-
1. [image]
2.[image]
3. [image]

but the changes are not reflecting. I might have missed something. Can anyone please help me here?

Comment: SO is not the place for asking tutorials. You might want to re-phrase your question to ask help for the actual issue, and include what you have done so far.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7381571/7149454

Comment: @NickKovalsky i want to localise a storyboard i am not able to do so.